# Console error when calling a Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I keep receiving an error when viewing the console after calling a Js function from a button

```
        <title>SDMT</title>

    <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/ping.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tables.css">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/clock.js"></script>

    <body>    
    <!--clock-->
    <div id="clockDisplay" class="clockStyle"></div>

    <!--Ping Tool-->
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Update Status" onclick="isValidURL()" />

</body>
```

I have tried putting the ping.js first in the header but this has not resolved the issue, this is my js file:

```
function isValidURL(url) {
    var encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(url);
    var isValid = false;

    $.ajax({
      url: "10.128.128.128",
      type: "get",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        isValid = data.query.results != null;
      },
      error: function(){
        isValid = false;
      }
    });

    return isValid;
}
```

If any one has any suggestion that would be awesome, I have cut out all of the other random elements aswell and still recieve this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
isValidURL @ ping.js:5
onclick @ index.html:124
```

Comment: Have you linked the jQuery library?

Comment: There are a variety of issues. First being that you haven't included jQuery. Second being that your `isValidURL` function will never work the way you think it does because `$.ajax` runs asynchronously and the function will return `false` before the callbacks ever execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.ajax is a Jquery Method. You need to include the Jquery Library into your document.

In your head add this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure its above the other scripts that need to access features of jQuery